# Which chart module/library should I use for Candlestick graphs in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, candlestick-chart

I tried using apex charts, but did not find proper doc for the `react-apexcharts`. I also tried `react-google-charts`, although it works fine, but it has unwanted spaces on sides which spoils the layout. I'm not sure about which module to use. Do you have a suggestion??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Author of ApexCharts here.
Thanks for reminding me to update the docs for the candlestick charts.
Here is the [page](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/candlestick/) that explains what should be the data-format.

Also, there is no major difference in options if you use react-apexcharts. The series prop should be given the required format as specified in the docs and rest will fall into places.

Comment: I need to indicate candles where I bought / sold (for example by adding a custom color or an arrow), is there a way to customise this behaviour on the chart?

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still asking which library to use for candlestick graphs.

Take a look Highcharts [Highcharts candlestick graph](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/candlestick)

Good documentation and great features